# File upload formdata with multer and req.file is undefined

Tags: javascript, express, upload, multer

I'm hoping someone can help save my sanity!

I'm just trying to do a simple file upload in React for an image but I can get the image to save correctly on disk. I can't open the image afterwards. The `req.body` comes out as a `Buffer` and try to `writeFile` with `req.body` but doesn't seem to work. The filesize is correct but it wont open. Tried to change the encoding but nothing works.

So I tried to even make a simpler example to see if perhaps I'm not handling the multipart formdata properly and this isn't working either.

On client side I use Axios to post to my API endpoint:

```js
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/upload', fd)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
```

And on the server side its a express app using multer:

```js
    const app = express();
    const upload = multer({
      dest: `uploads/`
    });
    app.use(cors());
    
    app.post('/', upload.single('image'), async(req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.file);
    
      res.send('end');
    });
```

When `console.log` the `req.file` it's always `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here? When `console.log` the headers it says that it is a multipart formdata.